# Ipod touch 5 stuck on voice over when restarted

Tags: ipod-touch, voiceover

I recently reset my ipod touch 5 and left it for the next day. When I turned it on the next day it somehow got on voice over mode and I can't swipe the screen without it speaking. What do I do?

Answer (score 1):

Click fast 3 times on the home button

Comment: And then perhaps disable it in Settings > General > Accessibility > VoiceOver